# Ruby Code Coverage: SimpleCov + MiniTest?

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler, minitest, simplecov

I integrated SimpleCov into my Ruby project (simple Ruby Gem project, no framework), which uses MiniTest for testing.

Here is `test_helper.rb`:

```rb
  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.start

  require 'minitest/autorun'
```

All my test files have `require 'test_helper.rb'`.

Running all the tests (either from RubyMine or with `bundle exec rake`) works and the HTML report is created.

However, it contains the coverage for... one of my test classes? I would expect to see a coverage report of all the classes called by the tests (which are under the standard `/lib` folder).

Here is the generaged report:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6305156/80513538-df68d080-8987-11ea-9858-43a3a2673e31.png

The link to the project: https://github.com/ruby-ee/ruby-stream-api/tree/10
It's a simple, barely started, Ruby Gem.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it. The SimpleCov documentation states that SimpleCov must be required and `SimpleCov.start` must be issued before any of the application code is required!

I had a `require` directive in my `*.gemfile`, therefore I had to add

```rb
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start do     # ommit test classes from the report
  add_filter 'test'
end
```

right there, instead of the `test_helper.rb`.

Comment: `add_filter "/test/"` might be a bit better, since as I understand `test` may erroneously match non-test files that include `test` substring.